# PHP Upload CSV file Extra Carraige Return

Tags: php, file-upload, csv

I am trying to use PHP to upload a CSV file (type:application/vnd.ms-excel) to my Unix box. And then FTP it to Mainframes.

The problem occurs in uploading when extra blank lines are added to the uploaded file at the end of each line, i can see this when i download the uploaded CSV file using ftp Command in cmd prompt.

No Extra lines appear in the CSV while viewing in Unix box.

When it FTPs it to mainframe i can see a dot added to each line. Hex Dec x'0D'

Could you please help me out in truncating this extra character while uploading?

My HTML File

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP Code "upload_file.php"

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("csv", "CSV");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $conn = ftp_connect("a.b.c.com") or die("Could not connect");
      ftp_login($conn,"login","pass");
      echo ftp_put($conn,"'dataset.name'","upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"],FTP_ASCII);
      ftp_close($conn);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php method.

You can open the file after storing it, iterating over each line and `trim()` them. You can print them back to the file (or just load everything, iterante and do a `file_put_contents()`). This should remove any whitespace from the beginning and the end before you upload it.

If you just want to remove it from the end, you can also use `rtrim()` or if you want to be more flexible you can do it with `preg_replace()` and something like `/\s*$/`.

Comment: Could you please share the coding for reading the contents and trimming and writting it back to the same file? i am just a begineer in PHP.